# Why again this is giving 0 output?

Tags: c

I wrote the program below to convert Celcius to
Fahrenheit. Why am I getting `0` if I remove that `+32` from the `return` of `ctof`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double ctof(double c)
{
    double a = (9 * c)/5.0;
    printf("Yeah");
    return a+32;
}

int main()
{

    double c, f;

    printf("Temperature :");
    scanf("%f", &c);

    printf("The temperature in fahranaiet is %f", ctof(c));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%f", &c);` ==> `scanf("%lf", &c);`

Comment: The `%f` format of `scanf` is for the `float` type. Since you use mismatching format specifier and argument, you will have *undefined behavior*. For a `double` value use the format `%lf`.

Comment: Activate your compiler warnings and read them

Comment: *"Please figure it out and reply me fast."* - Never write things like that. You're asking for free help. You should probably read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/6699433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [specifications](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for the format specifiers for `scanf`. Use `%lf` to read a `double`.

The `scanf` function uses macros to implement accepting a variable number of parameters. Due to this, type checking is not possible and the program will try to write a `float` to a memory location reserved for a `double`. As a `double` is larger than a `float` this will most likely leave some bytes uninitialized, which leads to undefined behavior when those bytes are used in a computation such as in `ctof`.

> Why am I getting 0 if I remove that +32 from the return of ctof?

This happens to be the case on your machine, but is not necessarily the case. Since undefined behavior was invoked earlier, we cannot reason about what the program produces in general.

Answer (score 1):

> %f is for float data type use %lf for double.

```
#include <stdio.h>
//function to convert celcius to fahrenhiet.
double ctof(double c){
    double a = (c * 1.8) + 32;
    printf("Yeah");
    return a;
}

int main(){
    double c, f;
    printf("Temperature ka ka bha , Celcius mai : ");
    scanf("%lf", &c);
    printf("The temperatur in fahranite is %lf", ctof(c));
    return 0;
}
```